# How to say person A is calling(looking for) person B?

Tags: sentence-construction, spoken-english, informal-language, australian-english

Sometimes I am in a situation where one person(person A) needs another(person B), who(B) is working close to me but doesn't hear the first person(A) and then the first person(A) shouts to me to inform B to go near to them. The scenario is:

> A: Hey B come here.
>   A to me: Tell him(B) to come here

I am confused what should I say to B. If I translate from my native language, then I would say, "Hey B, A is **calling you**". But, I think this is not correct in English. May be *Hey, A is looking for you* or *A needs you* is more appropriate, but this doesn't signify that A is actually shouting/saying to B to go there. May be a better phrasing would be *Hey B, A is asking you to go to him*.

What is usual sentence to be used here in English and specifically in Australian English?

Comment: _"Mate, 'A' wants you."_?

Comment: @VarunNair But this doesn't signify the fact that A has been shouting recently to B. It could be that A was waiting for B for an hour in an office. I want to emphasise that A was speaking loudly to B.

Comment: Why do you think that "*Hey B, A is calling you*" is not correct? That's the primary way of saying it as far as I know.

Comment: @SovereignSun Because I literally translated it from my language(Punjabi). And when I looked for the meaning of _call_, it meant only to make a telephone.

Comment: @user31782 the word "**call**" has many meanings.

Comment: @SovereignSun Yeah looking closely at all the meanings I find "_cry out to (someone) in order to summon them or attract their attention._". Does _cry_ here mean simply _speaking_ or _shouting_, or does it meaning speaking with sorrow or grief?

Comment: Well, you can look that up too. "**cry out to/for someone**" - *To express a want or need (which is typically stated after "for")*

Comment: you could tell B, "Hey B, A wants you to go there" ..

Comment: The normal thing to say is that "A wants you" as suggested by Varun Nair.  It's not common to relay the fact that someone is raising their voice---this is normally not relevant. However, if for some reason you want to be explicit about this, then your original idea is best: "A is calling you."  Alternatives are "A is calling for you" and "A is yelling for you."  The latter implies that A might be doing so in an agitated manner.

Answer (score 1):

> Hey B, A is calling you

This sounds perfectly correct for the described case.

Another solution is `Hey B, A asks you to come over`